# Display Spearman correlations between pairs of boxplots in ggplot2/ggpubr

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, ggpubr

I have a plot with three boxplots and I need to display Spearman correlations between pairs of boxplots using ggplot2 or ggpubr.

It is easy to make a similar plot, but with pairwise p-values. For example,

```
library(ggpubr)
data("ToothGrowth")
df <- ToothGrowth
p <- ggboxplot(df, x = "dose", y = "len",
               color = "dose", palette =c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"),
               add = "jitter", shape = "dose")
my_comparisons <- list( c("0.5", "1"), c("1", "2"), c("0.5", "2") )
p + stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisons)
```

[image]

How can I make a similar plot but with Spearman correlations instead of p-values?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
dose_0.5 <- df[df$dose == 0.5,]
dose_1 <- df[df$dose == 1,]
dose_2 <- df[df$dose == 2,]

cor.test(dose_1$len,dose_2$len)
cor.test(dose_0.5$len,dose_2$len)
cor.test(dose_1$len,dose_0.5$len) 

p <- ggboxplot(df, x = "dose", y = "len",
               color = "dose", palette =c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"),
               add = "jitter", shape = "dose")
my_comparisons <- list( c("0.5", "1"), c("1", "2"), c("0.5", "2") )
p + geom_signif(test = "wilcox.test", 
                comparisons = list( c("0.5", "1"), c("1", "2"), c("0.5", "2") ),
                vjust = 0,
                textsize = 4,
                size = .5,
                step_increase = .08,
                annotations = c(cor.test(dose_1$len,dose_0.5$len)$estimate,
                                cor.test(dose_1$len,dose_2$len)$estimate,
                                cor.test(dose_0.5$len,dose_2$len)$estimate))
```

[image]

`df` is the `ToothGrowth`dataset. if you really want something like this, just replace the p.value with correlation staff, maybe you need to edit the legend or title to explain that the annotation upon is correlation coefficent.

By the way you can add `round()` in `annotation = ...` so the correlation coefficent won't be that long.

Comment: From Review: Please improve the description of you answer. If you have questions to ask, do it using comments, you should not do it in your answer.

Comment: This is a very helpful answer. Would it be possible to put the annotations in a loop?  In this way, a script could be run on a data set containing multiple levels. For example, if I have multiple groups (sometimes two groups, sometimes five) would it be possible to add in the annotations automatically instead of writing each one out individually?